# How can I replace ~60 print entries in 5 different files using vim or sed?

Tags: sed, vim, python

Fabfile (directory) containing Python files:

```
print "DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"+var
print "DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"
#print "DEBUG cfn_stackname: "+cfn_stackname
```

To:

```
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"+var)
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True")
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG cfn_stackname: "+cfn_stackname)
```

How can I replace all these entries with my Logger module?
Should I use vim or sed?

Comment: No, I corrected both typos.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the missing `)` on line two and the repeated `"` on line three are transcription mistakes?

```
sed 's/^#*print \(.*\)/LOGGER.DEBUG(\1)/' ujjain
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"+var)
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True")
LOGGER.DEBUG("DEBUG cfn_stackname: "+cfn_stackname)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do anything, e.g. the line:        print "DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: False" is still the same.

Comment: @ujjain Then you are doing something wrong. It works for me.  This would however change _all_ `print` statements, not just the debugging ones. I'm uncertain whether this is what's wanted or not.

Comment: I am using a MacBook. Does that matter? sed (GNU sed) 4.5 - Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc. - License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.

Comment: The working code on my MacBook is: sed 's/print \(.*\)/LOGGER.DEBUG(\1)/' fabfile

Comment: Python statements almost always are indented. Please try `sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*#*print \(.*\)/LOGGER.DEBUG(\1)/'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1="";print $0}' filename|sed "s/^/LOGGER.DEBUG\(/g"| sed "s/$/)/g"
```

output:

```
LOGGER.DEBUG( "DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True"+var)
LOGGER.DEBUG( "DEBUG fab_helper DRYRUN: True")
LOGGER.DEBUG( "DEBUG cfn_stackname: "+cfn_stackname)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Vim: Load all py files with `vim *.py` and then do:

```
:bufdo %s/^ *#\?print \("DEBUG .*\)$/LOGGER.DEBUG(\1)/
```

The command `:bufdo` runs the substitution command (`%s/...`) for every loaded file.
See `:help :bufdo`.